# Cannot connect with sqmcmd although MS SQL Server Management Studio can

Tags: sql-server

I have a case where I need to connect to a remote database. Using MS SQL Server Management Studio I can connect without any problems. But I have trouble doing the same with sqlcmd.

Can someone tell me what the Mgmt Studio does differently?

Right now, I'm doing this:

```
sqlcmd /S server_name -E
```

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Thanks,
Christian

Comment: Can you take a screenshot from SSMS (login dialog) and add it to the question? Does it involve an INSTANCE name, e.g. `SERVER\SQL1` in SSMS and you've only used `SERVER` in SQLCMD?

Comment: sqlcmd uses OleDB (native). SSMS uses SqlClient (managed). If your OleDB drivers are messed up, it could explain.

Comment: I think the problem has to do with intermittent connections. I just tried to connect again with SSMS and it also fails to connect.

Comment: But it's good to know that SSMS uses SQLClient!